# On rare occasions a jQueryUI accordion object is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Once in a while our website generates an internal error message about an object being undefined. We are using JQueryUI. Here is an example: "TypeError: X.accordion is not a function". The line of code triggering the error is in a minified version of jquery. The non-minified code looks as follows:

```
var $help = $('#help,#help2');
$help.accordion(
{
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true,
    header: '.helpItem',
    icons: false,
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

We have not been able to reproduce the error, but our production system generates the error several times a week.

You can see the function without having to log in to our website using the following instructions:

1. https://www.rephunter.net/manufacturers-sales-reps-find
2. Navigate down to the search box
3. Click on the spyglass.
4. On the results page, there is an accordion near the top, left of the page, which shows up briefly, but can be re-opened by clicking on "Show Help for The Page".

[image]

Comment: I suggest that you make your code runnable here if you want more help.

Comment: The problem with such a "toy" application suitable for posting is that it will "just work" and not have the production-like conditions that allow it to fail. That's why I provided the instructions for the live application. I understand the toy application would be a help in seeing the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Put the script tag at the bottom of your page or in a `$(document).ready()` :

```
var $help = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $help = $('#help,#help2');
   $help.accordion(
   {
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true,
    header: '.helpItem',
    icons: false,
    heightStyle: "content"
   });
});
```

Comment: And the $help variable defined outside ? @JeffreySimon

Comment: And the $help variable is also defined within the document ready section.

Comment: I think $help should be declared outside of doncument ready to be accessible by other parts of the code.

Comment: nAviD: I think you are on to something and that having $help outside of document ready could help. Will let you know.